# Listener problems with Canvas

Tags: java, swing, listener

I'm trying to do an multiplayer airHockey game in Java. I already have the server/client socket working. 
My frame has a cardLayout with 2 panels, the canvas and the jtable.
I want to do a lan scan to find servers, and then choose the server I want.
I made this scan and put it in a JTable in the cardLayout.
When I start the server it displays the canvas card directly, no problem with listeners.
But when I start the client it checks the lan then displays the jtable card. Once a server is chosed I show the canvas and connect to the server. Here is the problem, no listeners work, neither my windowListener nor the keyListener.

I tried many things but without success.

EDIT:
I just made an SSCCE about the problem:

```
public class test extends Canvas{
public static final int SERVEUR = 10, CLIENT = 20;
public static int STATUT;
JFrame frame;
CardLayout cardsC = new CardLayout();
Container container;
JPanel servPanel = null;
public BufferStrategy strategy;

public test() {
    Object[] options = {"SERVER", "CLIENT"};
    int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choisissez une option:", "Warning", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    if(answer == 0){
        STATUT = SERVEUR;
        newFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        gameLoop();
    }else if(answer == 1){
        STATUT = CLIENT;
        newFrame(); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        cardsC.show(container, "servs");
    }
}

public void connection(){
    if(servPanel != null) servPanel.removeAll();
    cardsC.show(container, "canvas");
    gameLoop();
}

private void gameLoop() {
    while(true){
        try {Thread.sleep(10);}catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

}

public void newFrame(){
    frame = new JFrame("Space Invaders 101");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,750));

    container = frame.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(cardsC);

    setBounds(0, 0, 600, 750);
    container.add(this, "canvas");

    setIgnoreRepaint(true);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    if(STATUT == CLIENT){
        servPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Valider");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                connection();

            }
        });
        servPanel.add(button);
        container.add(servPanel, "servs");
    }

    KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
    manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());

    requestFocusInWindow();
    requestFocus();

    createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategy = getBufferStrategy();
    cardsC.show(container, "servs");
    cardsC.show(container, "canvas");
}

private class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED){
            System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    new test();
}
```

}

So, you can try it, the keyListener is working when you chose SERVER whereas it's not if you chose CLIENT.
I figured out that if I don't go in gameLoop the keylistener works.
Also when the other card is displayed (not the canvas one) the keyListener works.

I'd like to know how I could get the listeners working if I displays first the jtable card.

If you need any more information.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - do you have a question?  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

When you swap a panel using the CardLayout, the new card does not receive focus so the KeyListener doesn't work. See [Card Layout Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) for more information and a solution.

However, the better solution is to NOT use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to listen for the specific keys that invoke Actions in your game.

Also, Swing is double buffered by default. There is no need to use a Canvas with a BufferStrategy.

Comment: This is all good.  Additionally, `Canvas` is a heavyweight AWT component. Though it's supposed to play well with lightweight Swing widgets, my experience is that you're always fighting quirks. Canvas used to perform better than JComponent-based graphics.  It looks like that advantage mostly disappeared with Java 7.

Comment: I tried with key blinding, still getting the same problem.Same with RXCardLayout. Thanks

Comment: I wrote that:  KeyStroke upStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false);
  Action upAction = new AbstractAction() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("up");
   }
  };
  frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(upStroke, "UP");
  frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("UP", upAction);
Is that good ?

Comment: yes I know, but I can't answer beofre 1h. So here it is: http://pastebin.com/KiFMYHhv